# K-means algorithm C++, swapping out Points?

Tags: c++, k-means, centroid

For my assignment, I have to apply a K-means algorithm to 600 data points, which all have 60 dimensions (or attributes, if you will). I'm storing the 600 data points into 6 clusters (so K=6) and this is what I have for it so far:

```
#include <iostream> //std::cout
#include <fstream> //std::ifstream
#include <string> //std::string
#include <sstream> //std::istringstream
#include <vector> //std::vector
#include <cmath> //std::cmath
#include <array> //std::array

#define K 6
#define MAX_ITERATIONS 10000000
#define NUM_ATTRIBUTES 60

struct Point{
        std::array<double, NUM_ATTRIBUTES> point;
        std::string classType;
};

struct Cluster{
        std::vector<Point> points;
        Point centroid;
};

int randNumGenerator(int max){
        int num = (rand() % max);
        return num;
}

void setData(Point p, std::string line, std::vector<Point> &data, int index){
        std::stringstream s(line);
        std::string classes[] = {"Normal", "Cyclic", "Increasing trend", 
                                "Decreasing trend", "Upward shift", "Downward shift"};

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ATTRIBUTES; i++){
                double num;
                if(s >> num){
                        p.point[i] = num;
                }
        }

        if(index > 0 && index <= 100){
                p.classType = classes[0];
        }
        else if(index > 100 && index <= 200){
                p.classType = classes[1];
        }
        else if(index > 200 && index <= 300){
                p.classType = classes[2];
        }
        else if(index > 300 && index <= 400){
                p.classType = classes[3];
        }
        else if(index > 400 && index <= 500){
                p.classType = classes[4];
        }
        else if(index > 500 && index <= 600){
                p.classType = classes[5];
        }
        data.push_back(p);
}

void initializeCentroids(std::vector<Point> &points, int num_clusters,
                                std::vector<Point> &centroids){
        Point p;
        std::vector<bool> numsUsedAlready(points.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < num_clusters; i++){
                int randNum = randNumGenerator(points.size());
                while(numsUsedAlready[randNum]){
                        randNum = randNumGenerator(points.size());
                }
                numsUsedAlready[randNum] = true;
                p = points[randNum];
                centroids.push_back(p);
        }
}

double calculateDistance(Point p, Point centroid){
        double ret = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < p.point.size(); i++){
                double distance = p.point[i] - centroid.point[i];
                ret += distance * distance;
        }
        return sqrt(ret);
}

void setCentroids(std::vector<Cluster> &clusters, std::vector<Point> centroids){
        for(int i = 0; i < centroids.size(); i++){
                Cluster c;
                c.points.push_back(centroids[i]);
                c.centroid = centroids[i];
                clusters.push_back(c);
        }
}

void setClusters(std::vector<Cluster> &clusters, std::vector<Point> points){
        int sendToCluster = 99999999;
        for(int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++){
                double minDist = 99999999999;
                Point p = points[index];
                for(int clusterNum = 0; clusterNum < clusters.size(); clusterNum++){
                        double tempDist = calculateDistance(p, clusters[clusterNum].centroid);
                        //std::cout << "dist: " << tempDist << " clusterNum: " << clusterNum << std::endl;
                        if(tempDist < minDist){
                                minDist = tempDist;
                                sendToCluster = clusterNum;
                        }
                }
                //std::cout << "Pushing  to clusterNUm " << sendToCluster << std::endl;
                clusters[sendToCluster].points.push_back(p);
        }
}

void updateCentroid(std::vector<Cluster> &clusters){
        for(int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++){
                Cluster c = clusters[i];
                for(int j = 0; j < NUM_ATTRIBUTES; j++){
                        double avg = 0;
                        for(int h = 0; h < c.points.size(); h++){
                                Point p = c.points[h];
                                avg += p.point[j];
                        }
                        double oldCentroidValue = c.centroid.point[j];
                        c.centroid.point[j] = avg / c.points.size();
                        std::cout << "old: " << oldCentroidValue << " new: " << c.centroid.point[j] << std::endl;
                }
        }
}

void k_clustering(std::vector<Point> &points, int num_clusters){
        std::vector<Point> centroids;
        initializeCentroids(points, num_clusters, centroids);
        std::vector<Cluster> clusters;
        setCentroids(clusters, centroids);

        /*for(int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < NUM_ATTRIBUTES; j++){
                        std::cout << clusters[i].centroid.point[j] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        */

        setClusters(clusters, points);
        updateCentroid(clusters);
        for(int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++){
                std::cout << i << " " << clusters[i].points.size() << std::endl;
        }
}

void readInputFile(std::ifstream &file, std::vector<Point> &data){
        std::string line;
        int counter = 0;
        while(getline(file,line)){
                counter++;
                Point p;
                setData(p, line, data, counter);
        }
}

void usageString(){
        std::cout << "Usage: output <input_file>" << std::endl;
}

char* checkFile(int argc, char *argv[]){
        if(argc < 2){
                usageString();
                exit(0);
        }
        else{
                char *inputfile = argv[1];
                return inputfile;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char *inputfile;
        inputfile = checkFile(argc, argv);

        std::ifstream input(inputfile);
        if(!input.is_open()){
                std::cerr << "Error: Data file doesn't exist" << std::endl;
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        srand(time(NULL));
        std::vector<Point> data;
        readInputFile(input, data);
        k_clustering(data, K);
        //printData(data);
        //Attribute closest cluster to each data point
          //For each point, calculate distance to each centroid
            //Assign point to cluster (and update centroid value, by finding mean values of all points)
          //Repeat until nothing changed or after a certain number of iterations

        return 1;
}
```

However, I noticed that my code works fine for only ONE iteration. But after that first iteration, in my 'setClusters' function, I'm pushing in a Point. I would have to MOVE that Point to a different cluster (if need be), however I'm confused on how to do that without taking the long route of deleting that Point from that cluster and then pushing it to the other one. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to go about swapping out the Point to a different cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to go over the whole code, but if you're interested in optimizing `setClusters()` then perhaps you could try C++'s move semantics and `vector`'s `emplace_back()`.

```
void setClusters(std::vector<Cluster> &clusters, std::vector<Point> points){
        int sendToCluster = 99999999;
        for(int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++){
                double minDist = 99999999999;
                Point& p = points[index];  // use a reference to avoid copying, unless you don't want to alter the original "points" vector
                for(int clusterNum = 0; clusterNum < clusters.size(); clusterNum++){
                        double tempDist = calculateDistance(p, clusters[clusterNum].centroid);
                        //std::cout << "dist: " << tempDist << " clusterNum: " << clusterNum << std::endl;
                        if(tempDist < minDist){
                                minDist = tempDist;
                                sendToCluster = clusterNum;
                        }
                }
                //std::cout << "Pushing  to clusterNUm " << sendToCluster << std::endl;
                clusters[sendToCluster].points
                                       .emplace_back(    // construct the new item in place
                                           std::move(p)  // by "moving" from p
                                        );
        }
        points.clear();  // clear the input vector, unless you don't want to alter it. cf. the comment on using references
}
```

Another idea would be for `Cluster`s to hold "indices" instead of actual "points". In this case, you would declare the structure to be something like:

```
struct Cluster{
        std::vector<int> pointIndices;
        Point centroid;
};
```

Then, in `setClusters()`, you can just push the indices:

```
void setClusters(std::vector<Cluster> &clusters, const std::vector<Point> points){  // points can be const now
        int sendToCluster = 99999999;
        for(int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++){
                double minDist = 99999999999;
                const Point& p = points[index];  // use a reference to avoid copying
                for(int clusterNum = 0; clusterNum < clusters.size(); clusterNum++){
                        double tempDist = calculateDistance(p, clusters[clusterNum].centroid);
                        //std::cout << "dist: " << tempDist << " clusterNum: " << clusterNum << std::endl;
                        if(tempDist < minDist){
                                minDist = tempDist;
                                sendToCluster = clusterNum;
                        }
                }
                //std::cout << "Pushing  to clusterNUm " << sendToCluster << std::endl;
                clusters[sendToCluster].pointIndices
                                       .push_back(index);  // cheap compared to pushing a "Point"
        }
}
```

I hope it helps.